# Bad argument #-2 to 'insert' (Proxy expected, got nil)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Im having a problem here I don't know how to resolve this, ben trying anything that I know to resolve this still no solution, please help

I have 2 modules

main.lua:

```
local comboBox = require( "dog" )

local a = display.newGroup()
local bang = {1,2,3}
local bang2 = {4,5,6}

local dog1 = comboBox.newComboBox( "Choose",100,200,100,32, "center", 32,bang)
local dog2 = comboBox.newComboBox( "Choose",200,100,100,32, "left", 32,bang2)

local b = display.newRect(0,0,10,10)

dog1:printAge()
dog2:printAge()

dog1:setTextColor(1,0,0)
dog2:setTextColor(0,1,1)

a:insert(b)
a:insert(dog1)-- error is here
```

external module dog.lua:

```
local comboBox = display.newGroup()
local nComboBox = display.newGroup()
local widget = require("widget")
local comboBox_mt = { __index = comboBox }  -- metatable
-- test = {}
-- local t = {}

-------------------------------------------------
-- PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
-------------------------------------------------

local function getDogYears( realYears ) -- local; only visible in this module
    -- return realYears * 7
end

--Scroll View

local function scrollListener( event )

local phase = event.phase
if ( phase == "began" ) then print( "Scroll view was touched" )
elseif ( phase == "moved" ) then print( "Scroll view was moved" )
elseif ( phase == "ended" ) then print( "Scroll view was released" )
end

-- In the event a scroll limit is reached...
if ( event.limitReached ) then
    if ( event.direction == "up" ) then print( "Reached top limit" )
    elseif ( event.direction == "down" ) then print( "Reached bottom limit" )
    elseif ( event.direction == "left" ) then print( "Reached left limit" )
    elseif ( event.direction == "right" ) then print( "Reached right limit" )
    end
end

return true
end

-- Create the scrollview widget
local function createScrollView(sx,sy,sWidth,sHeight,sList)
    -- body
    scrollView = widget.newScrollView
    {
    top = sy+sHeight/2,
    left = sx-sWidth/2,
    width = sWidth,
    height = sList*sHeight,
    scrollWidth = 0,
    scrollHeight = sList*sHeight,
    horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
    listener = scrollListener
}
-- scrollView.anchorX = 1
-- scrollView.anchorY = 0
return scrollView
end


--show drop box and its content
local function createDropDown(dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight, dList)

-- local dropRect = display.newRect(dx,dy+dHeight,dWidth,dHeight)
-- dropRect:setFillColor(1,1,0)
local newListContent = {}
Y = 0+dHeight/2

for i = 1,#dList do

    local optionsForList = {
        text = dList[i],     
        x = 0,
        y = Y,
        font = native.font,   
        fontSize = 32,
        align = "left" --new alignment parameter
    }

    newListContent[i] = display.newText(optionsForList)
    newListContent[i].anchorX = 0
    newListContent[i]:setFillColor(1,0,0)
    Y = Y + dHeight+1
    scrollView:insert(newListContent[i])
    nComboBox:insert(scrollView)
    end

end


--drop box
local function bringDropDown( self, event )
    -- body
local phase = event.phase
if phase == "began" then
    -- print(self.text)
elseif phase == "moved" then

else

    self.text = "Choose an Item"
    if self.state == "n" then
        createScrollView(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, #self.list)
        createDropDown(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height, self.list)
    else

    end


end

return true

end
-------------------------------------------------
-- PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
-------------------------------------------------

--Create new ComboBox
function comboBox.newComboBox( name, cx, cy, cWidth, cHeight, cAlign, cFontSize, cList)     -- constructor

-- local autoincre = 0
-- local tContents = {}

local comboBoxTextOptions = {
    text = name,     
    x = cx,
    y = cy,
    width = cWidth,     --required for multi-line and alignment
    height = cHeight+1 ,
    font = native.font,   
    fontSize = cFontSize,
    align = cAlign --new alignment parameter
}

local comboBoxFill = display.newRect(cx,cy,cWidth,cHeight)
local tNewComboBox = {
    display.newText(comboBoxTextOptions),
    -- name = name or "Unnamed",
    -- age = ageInYears or 2
}
print(#cList)
tNewComboBox[1].touch = bringDropDown
tNewComboBox[1].name = name
tNewComboBox[1].state = "n"
tNewComboBox[1].list = cList
tNewComboBox[1]:addEventListener("touch",tNewComboBox[1])
nComboBox:insert(comboBoxFill)
nComboBox:insert(tNewComboBox[1])
return setmetatable( tNewComboBox, comboBox_mt )
end


-------------------------------------------------

function comboBox:setTextColor(cx,cy,cz)
self[1]:setFillColor(cx,cy,cz)
end

-------------------------------------------------


return comboBox, nComboBox
```

stack traceback:

```
File: main.lua
Line: 36
Bad argument #-2 to 'insert' (Proxy expected, got nil)

stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'insert'
main.lua:36: in main chunk
```

Right now still thinking of what to do in here. this is the only thing that holds back my project. Please help, Thanks :)

Comment: Add `print( dog1, dog2 )` to confirm whether the objects are being created. Also, paste the entire stack traceback in your question.

Comment: Yes it is created, as a table though

Comment: added stack traceback

Comment: I have the exact same error. It occurs when I'm recycling cells (groups) from a table view (scroll view). I collect unused cells in a pool by removing them from the scrollview. When I'm using cells from my recycling pool, it prompts this error when I try to insert them in the scrollview. So far the only turnaround I found is to **not** recycle my cells :'(

Answer (score -1):

You can't use metatables directly with Corona display objects.
newComboBox must return display object in that case.

Comment: can I return it as a group?

Comment: Group is also display object. What I meant, that you must insert display object to group (can be other group). Since newComboBox product is inserted later, it must produce display object.

Comment: I've done that too and i returned it with comboBox(nComboBox) at dog.lua

Comment: Nope. There is difference. You are assigning to dog1 variable return value from newComboBox method. Then you are trying to insert it. Since it's not display object, you can't.

Comment: I did not understand this sorry, I've done something that works, but it overwrites the previous comboBox, that's why I used this metatable

Comment: okay maybe I got it, dog1 = a function, so I must make it as a display object, however I have a lot of a display object in there, that works as one

Comment: So make it a display group and put contents in it. Display group also behaves just like any other table, so you can attach functions and variables to it. But if you use setmetatable you lose Corona display object properties.

Comment: But if I do that, If I create 2 of these objects the 1st object will be overwritten and it will be forgotten by corona. and I can;t manipulate it anymore even though If I use different variables for it,

Comment: You need to work your way out of creating objects. It can be done by many ways. Look up spawning objects in corona and check some OO tutorials.

Comment: @Piotr Is there any way that this answer can be made more complete, by explaining what would work and addressing some of the comments in the answer so we don't have to read 20 comments that culminate in "you need to read more"?

Comment: Nope. Those are basics. I could paste documentation here, but I think that's not the point.